# How can I have fnpct kern \cite superscripts like it kerns \footnote?

Tags: citing, kerning, fnpct

`fnpct` seems to do an excellent job adjusting the kerning between periods/commas and footnote symbols. This AdaptNote command does switch positions with interpunction, but does no kerning. Can I use `fnpct` to perform the kerning?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{super,comma,open=,close=}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\AdaptNote\cite{o+m}[\@mpfn]{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#NOTE{#2}}{#NOTE[#1]{#2}}}
\begin{document}
    Footnotes \footnote{foo}, and citations \cite{citekey1}, exhibit different kerning \cite{citekey1,citekey2}.
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
        \bibitem{citekey1} First citation.
        \bibitem{citekey2} Second citation.
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to move the footnote markers a little above punctuation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{super,comma,open=,close=}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\setfnpct{
  after-comma-space={-0.2em},
  after-dot-space={-0.2em},
}

\makeatletter
\AdaptNote\cite{o+m}[\@mpfn]{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#NOTE{#2}}{#NOTE[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Footnote\footnote{x} footnote\footnote{foo}, and citations \cite{citekey1}, 
exhibit different kerning \cite{citekey1,citekey2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{citekey1} First citation.

\bibitem{citekey2} Second citation.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I didn't realise that other fnpct functionality worked for non-footnotes.